# Porque mi estado no cambia react redux en el useeffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

> tengo un problema, cree mi ruta privada prvate route pero cuando intento entrar
> a la ruta privada despues del dispatch loginSucces hago console.log al isAuth y mi estado no cambia pero cuando veo en reac-tools mi estado si cambioo

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {  Navigate,Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

import { fetchUserToken } from "../../services/isAuth";
import {   loginSuccess, loginFail} from "../login/loginSlice";



export const PrivateRoute =  () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { isAuth } = useSelector(state => state.login);
    const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
        try {
                await fetchUserToken();
                dispatch(loginSuccess())
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(loginFail(error))
        }
      }

    useEffect(()=>{
            dispatch(fetchUser())
    },[dispatch])

    return (isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />)
};
```

Archivo Slice:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"; 
const initialState = {   
    isLoading: false,   
    isAuth: false,   
    error: "", };  

const loginSlice = createSlice({
    name: "login",
    initialState,   
    reducers: {     
        loginPending: (state) => {       
             state.isLoading = true;     
        },
        loginSuccess: (state) => {       
             state.isLoading = false;
             state.isAuth = true;
             state.error = "";     
        },     
        loginFail: (state, { payload }) => {       
             state.isLoading = false;       
             state.isAuth = false;       
             state.error = payload;     
        },   
    }, 
});
```

Comment: ¿Si entra a la ruta privada? Compárte los estractos de `loginSlice `, se supone que `loginSuccess()` debería llevar argumentos, ¿O cómo notificas al slice que cambia su estado? Saludos

Comment: el loginsucces lo que hace es que cambia el estado a true(isAuth)

Comment: `import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  isAuth: false,
  error: "",
};

const loginSlice = createSlice({
  name: "login",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loginPending: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    },
    loginSuccess: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isAuth = true;
      state.error = "";
    },
    loginFail: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isAuth = false;
      state.error = payload;
    },
  },
});`

Answer (score 0):

Revisé el caso y el código debería entrar a la ruta privada `<Outlet />` sin problemas, después del `useEffect`.

No esta claro lo que se quiere realizar con el `token` y el `user`, pero parece una especie de validación.

Comparto mis notas:

---

> cuando intento entrar a la ruta privada despues del dispatch loginSucces hago console.log al isAuth y mi estado no cambia

No se puede obtener el cambio de estado inmediatamente después de `dispatch(loginSuccess())`, así como se plantea con `console.log`:

```
const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
            await fetchUserToken();
            //React:los cambios de estado son operaciones Async
            //React:el estado isAuth ya cambio, pero no en este scope
            dispatch(loginSuccess())
            //React:en este scope isAuth aun sigue siendo false
            console.log(isAuth);
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(loginFail(error))
    }
}
```

El cambio de estado se encuentra en scope del `redux-store` y no en el scope de `fetchUser()`.

Ahora bien, se puede crear otra función `slice reducer` en `loginSlice`, por ejemplo `isUserVerified()`, y ahí trabajar con el cambio de estado mas reciente en el `store`:

```
//extracto de metodo en reducers loginSlice
isUserVerified: state => {
    //React-redux: aquí puedo hacer verificaciones
    //React-redux: por ejemplo con el token y el user
    //React-redux:tengo acceso directo al store y al estado mas reciente
    console.log("estado mas reciente de isAuth:",state.isAuth)
}
```

Luego, invocarla inmediatamente después de `dispatch(loginSuccess())`:

```
const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
        try {
                await fetchUserToken();
                //los cambios de estado son operaciones Async
                //el estado isAuth ya cambio, pero no en este scope
                dispatch(loginSuccess())
                //en este scope isAuth aun sigue siendo false
                console.log(isAuth);
                //invoca a otro reducer, el store ya tiene el nuevo estado
                //que cambio debido a loginSuccess
                //por ser dispatch, puedo enviar un action object
                //por ejemplo el token
                dispatch(isUserVerified())
                //react: puedo enviar un action object como args
                //dispatch(isUserVerified({type:'VERIFICATION', payload:token}))
            } catch (error) {
                dispatch(loginFail(error))
        }
    }
```

El patrón mostrado arriba, puede ser una forma secuencial de trabajar con los cambios de estado en `redux`, antes de devolver el componente.

Sin embargo, hay que vigilar que nuestras funciones/metodos reducer, sean [funciones puras](https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/three-principles#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions).

#### Redux-thunk

Hay un caso conocido como [`conditional dispatch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674575/5843452), donde se puede usar [redux-thunk para obtener el estado actual del store](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#accessing-state). Sin embargo esto implíca agregar una capa extra de complejidad a tu aplicación.

De lo general, Redux-thunk se usa para crear [funciones impuras](https://redux.js.org/understanding/history-and-design/prior-art#flux). Es decir, funciones que por ser impuras, no deben ser parte de un `reducer`.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.